# Update SQL statements not working in external class

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am trying to update a MySQL database table.
I have found out that when i insert the Update SQL statement inside
an external class i get the following error when executing the SQL:
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

If i however execute the SQL statement inside the file where i recieve
the values i want to update using POST, i dont get that error. Even though
i use the same connection class in both context.

I user localhost as server and i login using the username "root".
I dont have a password, and just pass an empty string as the password. In all other contexts that does not give any problem, and the SQL works fine.

I have tried to associate a password with the User and change it in the config.inc.php file to make sure everything is setup as it should. But even with a password, it still comes with the error statement saying it denies access using the password "YES". Which is weird because i have not asked it to use that password.

The procedure that does not work:
UpdateClass:

```
class DataUpdaters extends DataConnector {
    public $BrugerID = "Unset";
    public $Password = "Unset";
    public $Email = "Unset";
    public $Fornavn = "Unset";
    public $Efternavn = "Unset";
    public $Telefon = "Unset";
    public $BeskedID = "Unset";
    public $Laest = "Unset";

    function UpdateUser() {
        $Con = $this->CreateCon();
        $UpdateBruger = "UPDATE brugere SET Password='" . $this->Password. "', Email='" . $this->Email . "' WHERE Id=" . $this->BrugerID . " ;";
        mysqli_query($Con, $UpdateBruger);
        mysqli_close($Con);
    }

    function UpdateProfile() {
        $Con = $this->CreateCon();
        $UpdateProfile = "UPDATE profiler SET Fornavn ='" .$this->Fornavn . "', Efternavn='" . $this->Efternavn. "', Telefon='" . $this->Telefon . "' WHERE BrugerID=" . $this->BrugerID . ";";
        mysqli_query($Con, $UpdateProfile);
        mysqli_close($Con);
    }
```

The DataConnector it extends:

```
class DataConnector {
    //Connection Properties
    public $ServerName = "localhost";
    public $UserName = "root";
    public $Password = "";
    public $DBName = "alpacadb";

    function CreateCon() {
        $ReturnCon = mysqli_connect($this->ServerName, $this->UserName, $this->Password, $this->DBName);
        return $ReturnCon;
    }
}
```

How i pass the information inside the php file where i recieve the info:

```
            $Password = $_POST['Password'];
            $Email = $_POST['Email'];
            $Fornavn = $_POST['Fornavn'];
            $Efternavn = $_POST['Efternavn'];
            $Telefon = $_POST['Telefon'];

            $Updaater = new DataUpdaters();
            $Updaater->Password = $Password;
            $Updaater->Email = $Email;
            $Updaater->BrugerID = $BrugerID;
            $Updaater->UpdateUser();

            $Updaater->Fornavn = $Fornavn;
            $Updaater->Efternavn = $Efternavn;
            $Updaater->Telefon = $Telefon;
            $Updaater->UpdateProfile();
```

The procedure that does work:

```
           $Connector = new DataConnector();
           $Con = $Connector->CreateCon();
            $Password = $_POST['Password'];
            $Email = $_POST['Email'];
            $Fornavn = $_POST['Fornavn'];
            $Efternavn = $_POST['Efternavn'];
            $Telefon = $_POST['Telefon'];

            $UpdateUser = "UPDATE brugere SET Password='" . $Password. "', Email='" . $Email . "' WHERE Id=" . $BrugerID. " ;";
            mysqli_query($Con, $UpdateUser);

            $UpdateProfile = "UPDATE profiler SET Fornavn ='" .$Fornavn . "', Efternavn='" . $Efternavn . "', Telefon='" . $Telefon . "' WHERE BrugerID=" . $BrugerID . ";";
            mysqli_query($Con, $UpdateProfile);
            mysqli_close($Con);
```

I expected that it wouldnt matter if the SQL statements was in a class,
But when i place it in a class i get the errormessage
"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)".
Even though the user, server and database information is the same in the two ways of updating my database table.

Comment: Thanks for the Advice, i will look into that. This is just a project to train PHP and programming in general, so security is not my primary priority at this state. But at some point it will be.

Comment: You are learning very bad habits which will come back to hunt you. Find a better learning resource.

Comment: So far, i have taken the PHP course on sololearn.com, and frequently use w3schools.com. Do you have any Recommendations?

Comment: Yes. Stop using w3schools. It is known for very bad examples. Check out articles at https://phpdelusions.net/

Comment: Well that looks interesting, i will look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning $Password in both classes.

```
public $Password = "Unset";
```

in DataUpdaters overrides the empty password of the base class. Use a different variable name in one of these classes to resolve the connection issue.